# Can not connect to pgAdmin server

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL on Windows 10 and the server appears to be in Task Manager. However, I get this error when opening pgAdmin4:

Failed to connect to the pgAdmin application server. Click here to try again.

Any ideas for what the problem is?

Comment: Is there any further information in the event viewer? How are you trying to connect to the service, through a browser?

Answer (score 14):

Did you try running the pgAdmin application as an administrator ?
I was having the same issue, but ran the application as an administrator and was able to connect.

Comment: the correct answer.. worked for me atleast.

Comment: wow.. that saved me reinstall of pgadmin for second time.. thank you!

Answer (score 8):

I installed pgAdmin 4 via the EnterpriseDB PostgreSQL installer as well as the stand-alone Windows installer and had the same problem both times. Then I came across this: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs4/dev/desktop_deployment.html

It seems the Windows installer configures pgAdmin for server mode, and we need to switch it to Desktop mode. Why the installer does not have an option for this I do not know.

You should be able to getting it working by doing the following:

- Modify config_local.py file in web folder, adding  `SERVER_MODE = False`
- Install [python for windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), checking the box to add it to your path
- Install the python packages necessary to run setup.py (see below)
- Delete C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db since upgrade mode seems to not work.
- Run `python setup.py` from any command prompt

Here are the python packages I think I installed to get setup.py to work

```
pip install flask
pip install flask_security
pip install flask_babel
pip install django-htmlmin
pip install python-dateutil
pip install flask_sqlalchemy
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time!

Comment: You saved me days of work !!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with pgAdmin 4 1.6 on Windows 7. The solution was simply to delete %appdata%\pgAdmin which was created by an earlier version. On systems other than Windows, there probably is a pgAdmin directory in your user directory. Of course, all session settings etc. are gone after deleting this.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10

Comment: This also worked for me on Windows 10 after having installed pgAdmin 4 v2 RC. The v2 Release Candidate didn't work fine for me and when I wanted to use pgAdmin 4 1.6 it showed the message "application server could not be contacted". Deleting %appdata%\pgAdmin solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with pgadmin 3.0 on windows server 2016. What I did is not actually a solution but solved my problem at, least. I switch to an older version 2.1 that worked like a charm.